# Windows 8.1 - Any way to legally obtain the ISO file?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I just bought Windows 8.1 and I would like to download the ISO file so I can make a bootable key for my new computer. Microsoft provided me an executable file called `OSGS14-WindowsSetupBox-32bitand64bit-English-4141408`.

Since I have a Mac laptop, I made a virtual machine running Windows 7 64bits, and I tried to run this executable, yet it fails since my screen resolution is too low (and I cannot increase it). It requires 1024x768 and I have 1280x674. Basically, it says I do not meet the standards of Windows 8.1 so I can't continue. My other computer (which I will install Windows 8.1 on) has no operating system to the Mac is my only solution.

Now I am a bit worried, is there any way I get this ISO file from a "sane" source ? I have a key any way, does Microsoft provide a link to this ISO file ?

Comment: The magnets on mydigitallife forums are verified to be good.

Comment: None of the answer given in this link can help me, since I cannot run any executable provided by Microsoft on my Virtual Machine, because of the resolution. Just tried all of them, it fails each time for the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, having a backup copy of *most* software products **is** legal. The illegal thing is activating or using it **without** having paid for it.

That's why your computer has the serial key printed on a sticker, you can reinstall a copy of that O.S. and *re-activate* it. You've already **paid** for that **license** along with the hardware when you purchased your sistem.

**TL;DR**: You pay for a license, not for a copy of the actual binaries, so *obtaining a license from an **illegal** source* is what's really illegal.

Comment: That's why I am just asking for a safe link ;)

Comment: You can even download a clean copy from  _the pirate bay_, as long as you don't activate it using serials or loaders. Also, this site was not made to share download links, only knowledge.

Comment: So I shouldn't be scared about backdoors and such ?

Comment: If you're not an important businessman or somebody that should really worry about that: no.